# strange indexing Error

Tags: python, indexing

just started programming with python (actually programming in general) and wrote a short program which persistently refuses to work properly. Though the output looks fine, there are still some Error lines I can´t get rid off. So I would be grateful for any help/suggestions.
Here is the code:

```
# takes a list with 5 columns per line as an input
# last name, first name, 3 score - values (exam1, exam2, final)
# prints out a formatted table with first name, last name and a weighted score sum

def parse_line(line_str):
    '''
    :param line_str: expects a line of form last, first, exam 1, exam2, final
    :return: a tuple containing first+last and list of scores
    '''
    field_list = line_str.strip().split(",")
    name_str = field_list[1] + " " + field_list[0]
    score_list = []
    for element in field_list[2:]:
        score_list.append(int(element))
    return name_str, score_list


def weighted_grade(score_list, weights=(0.3, 0.3, 0.4)):
    ''' 
    :param score_list: expects 3 elements in score_list
    :param weights: multiples each element by its weigth
    :return: returns the sum
    '''
    grade_float = \
        (score_list[0] * weights[0]) + \
        (score_list[1] * weights[1]) + \
        (score_list[2] * weights[2])
    return grade_float

grade_file = open("/home/jan/Desktop/Grades.txt", "r")              
print("{:>13s} {:>15s}".format("Name", "Grade"))                # header   of the table
print("-" * 30)
for line_str in grade_file:
    name_str, score_list = parse_line(line_str)                 # passing it the first function, multiple assignment
    grade_float = weighted_grade(score_list)
    print("{:>15s} {:14.2f}".format(name_str, grade_float))     # final table
```

And this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jan/PycharmProjects/introduction/more.py", line 27, in <module>
         Name           Grade
    name_str, score_list = parse_line(line_str)
------------------------------
  File "/home/jan/PycharmProjects/introduction/more.py", line 8, in parse_line
     John Smith          30.00
    name_str = field_list[1] + " " + field_list[0]
 Larry CableGuy          30.00
IndexError: list index out of range
     Try Harder          40.00
   Monty Python         100.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line in your file without a comma in it. Usually this happens because the line is entirely empty. As a result, `str.split()` returns a list with at most 1 element in it so trying to index element 1 (the 2nd) fails.

Skip such lines:

```
for line_str in grade_file:
    if ',' not in line:
        continue
    name_str, score_list = parse_line(line_str)                 # passing it the first function, multiple assignment
```

Comment: btw. I´m really impressed how fast you found the Error